# model fit failed at inference_train_function

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I faced some issue on the model fit and new to Tensorflow.

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 embedding (Embedding)       (None, 50, 5)             30

 lstm (LSTM)                 (None, 64)                17920

 dense (Dense)               (None, 6)                 390

=================================================================
Total params: 18,340
Trainable params: 18,340
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

When it reached the model.fit, somehow it pop up these sorts of error messages. The purpose of this training is on the text analysis on the git log and categorised it whether it belongs to either new feature, fix and many more.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 138, in <module>
    model_training()
  File "test.py", line 136, in model_training
    model.fit( training_padding_sentence, training_general_label, epochs = 20)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 138, in <module>
      model_training()
    File "test.py", line 136, in model_training
      model.fit( training_padding_sentence, training_general_label, epochs = 20)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 859, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 374, in call
      return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 451, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 589, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/layers/embeddings.py", line 197, in call
      out = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.embeddings, inputs)
Node: 'sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup'
indices[0,0] = 15 is not in [0, 6)
         [[{{node sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3232]
```

Comment: Hi @Will could you please provide a stand alone code to reproduce the issue. Thanks!